# How to handle size and position of controls in Android's Activity for portrait and landscape orientation?

Tags: android

I want to desing a GUI for android's tablet. By default i want to use landscape orientation of this application, so i placed the controls (text boxes, text views etc) accordingly, but when i change the orientation of tablet from landscape to portrait, whole GUI of activity gets distrubed. Can anybody guide/help me what is the best approach for designing of GUI in android such that controls appearance should remain correct in either orientation (portrait or landscape)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create another folder in the res directory called "layout-land". Put the layout file for landscape in this folder and the one for protrait mode in the normal "layout" folder. Both files must have the same name. Android will automatically chose the correct layout depending of the current orientation of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below, it will provide all information about how to design an application to support multiple screens with different sizes and resolutions.

[Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks Yugandhar for sharing nice article.